# Ejabberd: cannot enable mod_mam

Tags: mysql, erlang, ejabberd

I'm running Ejabberd 17.01 on Ubuntu 16.4, and I need to log all messages in a database. With the module `mod_mam` this should be straightforward task. What I've done so far according to the [official documentation](https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/databases/mysql/):

- Creating a MySQL database
- Importing the schema that comes with the Ejabberd installation
- Making the follow changes in the `ejabberd.yml` conf file

Code snippet:

```
auth_method: sql
default_db: sql
...

## MySQL server:
##
sql_type: mysql
sql_server: "localhost"
sql_database: "ejabberd"
sql_username: "someuser"
sql_password: "somepassword"
...
```

In principle, this seems to work. When I create new users, or users create their own accounts, I can see the additions to the corresponding MySQL table. That means that the database is used and can be accessed, I presume.

But now I want to enable `mod_mam`. According to the documentations and other sources on the Web, this should look something like this:

```
modules:
  mod_mam:  % <-- I had "mom_mam" here. Didn't notice the typo in the error message.
    iqdisc: no_queue
    db_type: sql
    default: always
```

However, with this, Ejabberd fails to start throwing the following error:

```
2017-01-27 08:44:50.242 [critical] <0.39.0>@gen_mod:start_module:162 Problem starting the module mom_mam for host <<"xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx">> 
options: [{iqdisc,no_queue},{db_type,sql},{default,always}]
error: undef
[{mom_mam,start,
          [<<"xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx">>,
          [{iqdisc,no_queue},{db_type,sql},{default,always}]],
          []},
{gen_mod,start_module,3,[{file,"src/gen_mod.erl"},{line,154}]},
{lists,foreach,2,[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1337}]},
{ejabberd_app,start,2,[{file,"src/ejabberd_app.erl"},{line,77}]},
{application_master,start_it_old,4,
                    [{file,"application_master.erl"},{line,273}]}]
2017-01-27 08:44:50.242 [critical] <0.39.0>@gen_mod:maybe_halt_ejabberd:170 ejabberd initialization was aborted because a module start failed.
```

I cannot find anything online, it just seems to work usually.

Comment: After searching and searching, and finally recompiling mod_mam, I eventually noticed the type in my ejabberd.yml conf file. It's mod_mam, not mom_mam.